# sass --watch encoding problems

Tags: css, ruby, encoding, utf-8

I started to use sass recently and found that i can use sass --watch to detect changes ( instead of redo sass bla.scss bla.css every time ) the problem is i got this :

> Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible character encodings: IBM437
>   and UTF-8

So eventho the error description is pretty clear i dont get why i got this, so i started looking this up on google and turns out it might be Ruby which isnt configured properly ( i dont get why my computer isnt encoded with UTF-8 by default but heh ) but i have no idea where to look for neither what to changes.
Im using the windows command prompt, and i'm just trying to design some web pages ( no ruby involved, just HTML and CSS )
Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Does your project path contains any non-latin letters, such as Cyrillic or any accented letters?

Comment: EDIT : i misread your question

Unfortunately yes, and it's a pain in the ass ( windows set up my session using my email adress, which got accent )

I'll move my project to C: and check if its okay

Answer (score 1):

Move your project to a path, that doesn't contain any non-latin letters (such as Cyrillic or accented letters).

Hope that helps.